# Some $_GET[] not working in PHP code

Tags: php

```
if($_GET["content"] ="foo"){
    echo("<h4>foo</h4>");
    exit;
}
```

When I type in URL "127.0.0.1/_/index.php?content=foo" it seems to output the previous code I wrote

```
if($_GET["content"] ="picture"){
    echo("Picture:<br>");
    echo("<img src='./ku~1.jpg'></img>");
    exit;
}
```

What is the problem here?

[image]

Comment: `=` vs `==`. (3 more to go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_GET["content"] ="picture"){
```

assigns `$_GET["content"]` the value `"picture"`. You want to use

```
if($_GET["content"] =="picture"){
```

and

```
if($_GET["content"] =="foo"){
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you started your file with

```
<?php
```

And you are assigning the value content by only using one =

Do this instead

```
if($_GET["content"] == "picture"){ 
  echo "Picture:<br>"; 
  echo '<img src="./ku~1.jpg"></img>'; 
  exit; 
}
```

You were also wrapping your echo with parentheses when they should be contained in quotations.

I forgot the first example... That should be:

```
if($_GET["content"] == "foo"){ 
    echo "<h4>foo</h4>"; 
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I don't know what the problem is, I checked for some problems in code and everything is how it should be.

Comment: Wow man, thanks a lot. That fixed the problem. I was really frustrating with this problem. Again, thanks :)